# data from Json string

Tags: java, android

I took response from server using bluetooth got like this. Now I need to get data from this string.

String is like

{
  "k2": {
    "mk1": "mv1",
    "mk2": [
      "lv1",
      "lv2"
    ]
  }
}

But it's not converting to JSONObject.

I need to get all values from here.

Comment: Is the response in string or json array?

Comment: it's in JSON, that has errors

Comment: i took response from server using bluetooth got like this now i need to take values from this one

Comment: You should parse the json, BUT is has a error: "LastModifiedDa12T14:54:38" you have to fix that first.

Comment: Your question is not specific, and you haven't shown any attempts of what you've already tried, hence it will probably be closed. Please edit your question, and be more specific - what exactly it is you want to extract from your data, what have you tried so far and where it isn't working as you expected...

Comment: now look at this modified string

Comment: "value" is not a JSONObject but is a JsonArray.. look at my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JSON library](http://www.json.org/java/index.html):

```
JSONObject element = new JSONObject(result);

String metadata= element.getString("odata.metadata");

JSONArray valueArr = element.getJSONArray("value");

for (int i= 0; i< valueArr.length(); i++) {

    //get single object from array
    JSONObject item = valueArr.getJSONObject(i);

    String patient = item.getString("PatientID");
    String firstName= item.getString("FirstName");
    ...
}
```

Note:
compared with [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), this library gives you the advantage of parserizzare (in simple mode) the json string complex and nested.

Comment: its trowing json exception unterminated String at

Comment: the JSON string contains special characters such as \, @, &, #, etc.. first you need convert them into their respective HEX value

Comment: we need to replace one by one symbol is there any other method

Comment: I'm sorry .. I did not find anything interesting .. I am afraid that we must act with the replace

Comment: you can try with apache library StringEscapeUtils: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html